# In Rails, execute block for both conditions: first_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Anybody know a Rails method that will allow me to look for an existing record or create a new one AND execute a subsequent block of code?

Example:

```
Model.where(parameters).first_or_create do |m|
  # execute this regardless of whether record exists or not
end
```

Similarly, the method `find_or_create_by` does not execute a block in either scenario.

I could use `if-else` statements but that will duplicate my code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-first_or_create), the block in your example will only execute if the record does not exist. But you don't need a block, nor an if-else:

```
m = Model.where(parameters).first_or_create
m.some_method # executes regardless of whether record exists or not
```

Be aware that some validations on the object may have failed and therefore `m` may not have persisted to the database yet.

Answer (score 21):

I picked this up from  [a great screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised) by ryan bates:

```
Model.where(parameters).first_or_create.tap do |m|
  # execute this regardless of whether record exists or not
end
```

(where `User#tap` selects the user)
I think this way looks a little cleaner, and you don't have to define another helper method as with Mischa's answer.  Both work fine though.

Comment: I've spent hours trying to get first_or_create to update a record if it exists and just found this page. So beautifully simple. Why isn't the .tap method mentioned in the first_or_create method docs!!

Comment: Just noticed a problem. When I use .first_or_create.tap a new user isn't being saved -> the create part of the code isn't executing. I've confirmed the information is being passed and 'puts @user.errors.to_a' is saying email can't be blank and password can't be blank. Anyone any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

@eric you need to save data before closing the block.

```rb
Model.where(parameters).first_or_create.tap do |m|
   # execute this regardless of whether record exists or not

   m.save
end
```